# Random spawn avoiding colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2D game with colleagues that is basically a fighting game on a vertical map with platforms. Right now I am spawning items on the map for player to gather, but I was wondering how could I do that while checking that I'm not in one of the platform's collider to avoid spawning the item in?

Comment: I meant to use unity2d tag but it convert it in unity3d everytime I change it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the overlap functions from `Physics2D` (for example [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBox.html)). Just generate a drop position and pass it to this function, if it returns `null` then the position is free. If you get unexpected results make sure to set the layer mask to the same as the platforms or whatever objects you don't want to intersect with.

Comment: Hello, thanks, it will be no use anymore for now as it was for our GGJ game but I'll make sure to remember it later when I use unity once again!